# Twice call of timer crashes my app: Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to develop a small android App. In that app I need to use Timer control, which will be fired at button click. What problem I'm getting is, First timer task call is working fine but when I'm calling it again my app getting crashes. Code using for timer task is:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask refreshRam;
final Handler handler = new Handler();
refreshRam = new TimerTask() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            handler.post(new Runnable() 
            {
                public void run() 
                {
                    txtFreeRam.setText(String.valueOf(getFreeRam()).toString());
                }
            });
        }}; 

    }


timer.schedule(refreshRam, 400);
```

I want to call my timer task only when I'm clicking on a button. It shouldn't be repeated...
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use timer.scheduleatfixedrate instead of schedule

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(refreshRam,400, 5000);

Answer (score 0):

When you reschedule a Timer, it throws:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: TimerTask is scheduled already
```

It seems that you can only use a timer for once.

In order to reschedule a Timer, you need to simply create a new instance of it, each time. like the following:

```
.
.
.

//first time; works fine!
timer = new Timer();
refreshRam = new TimerTask() { ... }
timer.schedule(refreshRam, 400);


//second time; also works fine!
//be sure to terminate the timer task that is running by calling timer.cancel()
timer.cancel();
timer = new Timer();
refreshRam = new TimerTask() { ... }
timer.schedule(refreshRam, 400);
```